# HTML5/CSS3: Any way to use pseudo elements to create a tag within a tag? (Avoiding Javascript)

Tags: html, css

As far as I can tell, there is no reliable method to do what I'm aiming to do, but I figure I'll ask the experts here anyway to see if it can be done.

I'm looking to create a simplified method of styling that allows someone to use a single tag with a class or ID that takes on the formatting of nested tags.  For example, a DIV that will appear to have another DIV inside it, allowing for more complex styling that is currently only possible by using nested elements.

An example of what I'd like to do would be something like:

```
<div class="nesteddiv">{content}</div>
```

and make it render as if it were:

```
<div class="outerdiv"><div class="innerdiv">{content}</div></div>
```

The goal might be to have the outerdiv and innerdiv have their own borders, backgrounds, margins, and spacing to create a complex style that can't be done on a single DIV (I don't think it's possible for a single DIV to have multiple borders)

I know there's pseudo-elements in ::before and ::after, allowing you to insert raw text or images inside the containing element before and after the content, but these can't insert html tags and have them render.  Is there another way to turn a single html element into something that renders as if it were multiple nested elements?  I'm trying to avoid Javascript because some of my viewers have Javascript disabled.  I know there's a way to create custom elements in Javascript as well as simply replacing all DIVs with a certain class with the more complex nested code, but I'd rather avoid all that extra coding if there's a more simple way already available in pure HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any good way to achieve this.

You can use `display: table` on the element. Assuming the contents aren't tabular elements, a `table-row` and `table-cell` [anonymous elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) will be created:

> Generate missing child wrappers:
>
> - If a child C of a 'table' or 'inline-table' box is not a proper table child, then generate an anonymous 'table-row' box around C and
>     all consecutive siblings of C that are not proper table children.
> - If a child C of a 'table-row' box is not a 'table-cell', then generate an anonymous 'table-cell' box around C and all consecutive
>     siblings of C that are not 'table-cell' boxes.

However, the problem is that you can't use CSS selectors to select those anonymous elements. So you can't style them. Therefore, this approach is usually useless.

An alternative doing the opposite: generate a pseudo-element wrapper of the desired element. This could be done with `::outside`, proposed by the [Generated and Replaced Content Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#wrapping):

> An '::outside' pseudo-element is one that is generated immediately
>   outside the pseudo-element's [superior](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#superior1).
>
> When given a parameter, '::outside(n)' represents an nth
>   pseudo-element generated immediately around the n-1th pseudo-element.
>
> For example, the following rules:
>
> ```css
> div { display: block; border: dashed; }
> div::outside { display: block; border: dashed; }
> div::outside(2) { display: block; border: dashed; }
> ```
>
> ...would result in the following rendering objects:
>
> ```
> ,-----------------------.   <-- border of ::outside(2)
> | ,-------------------. |   <-- border of ::outside
> | | ,---------------. | |   <-- border of DIV
> | | | DIV           | | |
> | | `---------------' | |
> | `-------------------' |
> `-----------------------'
> ```

However, this module is a draft which hasn't been updated since 2003, and I think it has never been implemented.

Some months ago I sent an email to the CSS WG suggesting a `::contents` pseudo-element which would generate a wrapper of the contents (not including `::before` nor `::after`). This pseudo-element would have `display: contents` by default, and thus it wouldn't be noticeable unless you changed the `display`. The email was ignored.

But I hope there will be some way to achieve this in the future. It makes no sense being able to "unwrap" contents with `display: contents` but not being able to wrap contents in a container.

Comment: ⁺¹ for the mention of `::outside`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do specific styling like borders and hovereffects etc. This is perfectly doable with pseudoelements.

The use of these elements extends far beyond putting in text and images. For example, a double border can very effectively be created by using a pseudo element. Just read up on pseudoelements, or be more clear exactly what styling you are trying to achive so we can help you more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve that with plain CSS. You can take a look at [::first-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line) and [::first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) pseudo-elements, but they have limited range of allowed CSS rules and applies only to first line or letter.